# Некорректно работает suggestView и с получением адреса по клику и запись в input

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Связал поле input с картой. При вводе данных, результат отображается на карте. Также при клике на карту полученный адрес должен записываться в обратно в input. Проблема в том, что при получений подсказок и выборе, окно подсказок не закрывается, и метки плодятся на карте и при каждом клике на карту в поле input снова появляются подсказки. Нужна помощь в доработке.

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var myInput = document.getElementById('search'),
    myInputMobile = document.getElementById('search__mobile'),
    myPlacemark,
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('form-map', {
      center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
      zoom: 9
    }, {
      searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    });

  // Слушаем клик на карте.
  myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
    var coords = e.get('coords');

    // Если метка уже создана – просто передвигаем ее.
    if (myPlacemark) {
      myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates(coords);
    }
    // Если нет – создаем.
    else {
      myPlacemark = createPlacemark(coords);
      myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
      // Слушаем событие окончания перетаскивания на метке.
      myPlacemark.events.add('dragend', function () {
        getAddress(myPlacemark.geometry.getCoordinates());
      });
    }
    getAddress(coords);
  });

  // Создание метки.
  function createPlacemark(coords) {
    return new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
      iconCaption: 'поиск...'
    }, {
      preset: 'islands#violetDotIconWithCaption',
      draggable: true
    });
  }

  // Определяем адрес по координатам (обратное геокодирование).
  function getAddress(coords) {
    myPlacemark.properties.set('iconCaption', 'поиск...');
    ymaps.geocode(coords).then(function (res) {
      var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0),
        address = firstGeoObject.getAddressLine();

      myPlacemark.properties
        .set({
          // Формируем строку с данными об объекте.
          iconCaption: [
            // Название населенного пункта или вышестоящее административно-территориальное образование.
            firstGeoObject.getLocalities().length ? firstGeoObject.getLocalities() : firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas(),
            // Получаем путь до топонима, если метод вернул null, запрашиваем наименование здания.
            firstGeoObject.getThoroughfare() || firstGeoObject.getPremise()
          ].filter(Boolean).join(', '),
          // В качестве контента балуна задаем строку с адресом объекта.
          balloonContent: address
        });
      myInput.value = address;
      myInputMobile.value = address;
    });
  }

  const getPlaceBySuggestView = (siggestViewGuessValue) => {
    ymaps.geocode(siggestViewGuessValue).then(res => {
      const firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
      const coords = firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates();

      const bounds = firstGeoObject.properties.get('boundedBy');
      myMap.setBounds(bounds, {
        checkZoomRange: true
      });

      myPlacemark = createPlacemark(coords);
      myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
      getAddress(myPlacemark.geometry.getCoordinates());

    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }


  const suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('search');
  suggestView.events.add('select', (e) => {
    const chosenAddress = e.get('item').value;
    getPlaceBySuggestView(chosenAddress);
  });
}
```

```css
.form-map__item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
}

.form-order__address {
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="form-wrapper__item">

  <li class="form-order__mobile form-order__suggest">
    <label class="form-order__caption form-order__title" for="search">Адрес</label>
    <input class="form-order__address form-order__validation form-order__placeholder" id="search" name="search"
      type="text" placeholder="example" required aria-label="Поле с адресом">
  </li>

  <li class="form-map__item" id="form-map">
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=c0183649-9564-47e9-a344-5e6d830db0fc"></script>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в саджест такую же проверку на существование метки на карте:

```
    if (myPlacemark) {
        myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates(coords);
    }
    else {
        myPlacemark = createPlacemark(coords);
```

Метки дублироваться перестанут: https://jsbin.com/qolivug/1/edit?js,output